# Determine if a String is a valid date before parsing

Tags: java, date, parsing

I have this situation where I am reading about 130K records containing dates stored as String fields. Some records contain blanks (nulls), some contain strings like this: 'dd-MMM-yy' and some contain this 'dd/MM/yyyy'.

I have written a method like this:

```
public Date parsedate(String date){

   if(date !== null){
      try{
        1. create a SimpleDateFormat object using 'dd-MMM-yy' as the pattern
        2. parse the date
        3. return the parsed date
      }catch(ParseException e){
          try{
              1. create a SimpleDateFormat object using 'dd/MM/yyy' as the pattern
              2. parse the date
              3. return parsed date
           }catch(ParseException e){
              return null
           }
      }
   }else{
      return null
   }

}
```

So you may have already spotted the problem. **I am using the try .. catch as part of my logic**. It would be better is I can determine before hand that the String actually contains a parseable date in some format then attempt to parse it.

So, is there some API or library that can help with this? I do not mind writing several different Parse classes to handle the different formats and then creating a factory to select the correct6 one, but, how do I determine which one?

Thanks.

Comment: If you decide to keep your solution, then please create only 2 instances of SimpleDateFormat and store them as constants in your class rather then creating them 130K times.

Comment: If you do store them as constants, make absolutely sure they are not used from multiple threads at once! I ran into problems with that earlier and contributed a FindBugs detector, that finds static DateFormats and Calendars. They are documented as non-thread-safe, but that's easy to miss. 
See http://dschneller.blogspot.com/2007/04/calendar-dateformat-and-multi-threading.html , http://dschneller.blogspot.com/2007/04/findbugs-writing-custom-detectors-part.html and http://dschneller.blogspot.com/2007/05/findbugs-writing-custom-detectors-part.html

Comment: @van: Don't do that. SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe, so if you use the class from more than one thread, things will blow up in your face.

Comment: I think that I will take everyones advice and continue using the try ..catch for now since this is really a one off app so I will not be running it in a production environment. But I will make the Functional Java the long term solution. It feels clean to me. Thanks.

Comment: After having gone through a long debugging process because of the thread safety problem, I would suggest using JODA. It is completely thread safe since all formatters  adn date times are immutable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Lazy Error Handling in Java](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/throwing-away-throws/) for an overview of how to eliminate try/catch blocks using an `Option` type.

[Functional Java](http://code.google.com/p/functionaljava) is your friend.

In essence, what you want to do is to wrap the date parsing in a function that doesn't throw anything, but indicates in its return type whether parsing was successful or not. For example:

```
import fj.F; import fj.F2;
import fj.data.Option;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import static fj.Function.curry;
import static fj.Option.some;
import static fj.Option.none;
...

F<String, F<String, Option<Date>>> parseDate =
  curry(new F2<String, String, Option<Date>>() {
    public Option<Date> f(String pattern, String s) {
      try {
        return some(new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(s));
      }
      catch (ParseException e) {
        return none();
      }
    }
  });
```

OK, now you've a reusable date parser that doesn't throw anything, but indicates failure by returning a value of type `Option.None`. Here's how you use it:

```
import fj.data.List;
import static fj.data.Stream.stream;
import static fj.data.Option.isSome_;
....
public Option<Date> parseWithPatterns(String s, Stream<String> patterns) { 
  return stream(s).apply(patterns.map(parseDate)).find(isSome_()); 
}
```

That will give you the date parsed with the first pattern that matches, or a value of type Option.None, which is type-safe whereas null isn't.

If you're wondering what `Stream` is... [it's a lazy list](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.19/javadoc/fj/data/Stream.html). This ensures that you ignore patterns after the first successful one. No need to do too much work.

Call your function like this:

```
for (Date d: parseWithPatterns(someString, stream("dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy")) {
  // Do something with the date here.
}
```

Or...

```
Option<Date> d = parseWithPatterns(someString,
                                   stream("dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy"));
if (d.isNone()) {
  // Handle the case where neither pattern matches.
} 
else {
  // Do something with d.some()
}
```

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. I will definitely have to look up Functional Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Don't be too hard on yourself about using try-catch in logic: this is one of those situations where Java forces you to so there's not a lot you can do about it.

But in this case you could instead use [`DateFormat.parse(String, ParsePosition)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)).

Comment: in java8 even though the docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) doesn't say it throws anything, the code indicates that it does throw a few RuntimeException :(

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of regular expressions to determine which format the string is in, and whether it matches any valid format.  Something like this (not tested):

(Oops, I wrote this in C# before checking to see what language you were using.)

```
Regex test = new Regex(@"^(?:(?<formatA>\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{2})|(?<formatB>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{3}))$", RegexOption.Compiled);
Match match = test.Match(yourString);
if (match.Success)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["formatA"]))
    {
        // Use format A.
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["formatB"]))
    {
        // Use format B.
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like three options if you only have two, known formats:

- check for the presence of `-` or `/` first and start with that parsing for that format.
- check the length since "dd-MMM-yy" and "dd/MM/yyyy" are different
- use precompiled regular expressions

The latter seems unnecessary.

Comment: Checking length should be faster in Java then searching for a char in.

Comment: @van: No need for premature optimization.

Answer (score 3):

If you formats are exact (June 7th 1999 would be either 07-Jun-99 or 07/06/1999: you are sure that you have leading zeros), then you could **just check for the length of the string** before trying to parse.

Be careful with the short month name in the first version, because Jun may not be June in another language.

*But if your data is coming from one database, then I would just convert all dates to the common format (it is one-off, but then you control the data and its format).*

Answer (score 3):

In this limited situation, the best (and fastest method) is certinally to parse out the day, then based on the next char either '/' or '-' try to parse out the rest. and if at any point there is unexpected data, return NULL then.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the patterns you gave are the only likely choices, I would look at the String passed in to see which format to apply.

```
public Date parseDate(final String date) {
  if (date == null) {
    return null;
  }

  SimpleDateFormat format = (date.charAt(2) == '/') ? new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy")
                                                   : new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
  try {
    return format.parse(date);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    // Log a complaint and include date in the complaint
  }
  return null;
}
```

As others have mentioned, if you can *guarantee* that you will *never* access the `DateFormat`s in a multi-threaded manner, you can make class-level or static instances.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions to parse your string. Make sure that you keep both regex's pre-compiled (not create new on every method call, but store them as constants), and compare if it actually is faster then the `try-catch` you use.

I still find it strange that your method returns `null` if both versions fail rather then throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

you could use split to determine which format to use

```
String[] parts = date.split("-");
df = (parts.length==3 ? format1 : format2);
```

That assumes they are all in one or the other format, you could improve the checking if need be

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to creating a SimpleDateFormat (or two) per iteration would be to lazily populate a ThreadLocal container for these formats.  This will solve both Thread safety concerns and concerns around object creation performance.

Answer (score 2):

A simple utility class I have written for my project.  Hope this helps someone.

Usage examples:

```
DateUtils.multiParse("1-12-12");
DateUtils.multiParse("2-24-2012");
DateUtils.multiParse("3/5/2012");
DateUtils.multiParse("2/16/12");




public class DateUtils {

    private static List<SimpleDateFormat> dateFormats = new ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat>();



    private Utils() {
        dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy")); // must precede yyyy
        dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy"));
        dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"));            

    }
        private static Date tryToParse(String input, SimpleDateFormat format) {
        Date date  = null;
        try {
            date = format.parse(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }

        return date;
    }

        public static Date multiParse(String input)  {
        Date date = null;
        for (SimpleDateFormat format : dateFormats) {
            date = tryToParse(input, format);
            if (date != null) break;
        }
        return date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On one hand I see nothing wrong with your use of try/catch for the purpose, it’s the option I would use. On the other hand there are alternatives:

1. Take a taste from the string before deciding how to parse it.
2. Use optional parts of the format pattern string.

For my demonstrations I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, because the `Date` class used in the question was always poorly designed and is now long outdated. For a date without time of day we need a `java.time.LocalDate`.

### try-catch

Using try-catch with java.time looks like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter ddmmmuuFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uu", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateTimeFormatter ddmmuuuuFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");

    String dateString = "07-Jun-09";

    LocalDate result;
    try {
        result = LocalDate.parse(dateString, ddmmmuuFormatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        result = LocalDate.parse(dateString, ddmmuuuuFormatter);
    }
    System.out.println("Date: " + result);
```

Output is:

> Date: 2009-06-07

Suppose instead we defined the string as:

```
    String dateString = "07/06/2009";
```

Then output is still the same.

### Take a taste

If you prefer to avoid the try-catch construct, it’s easy to make a simple check to decide which of the formats your string conforms to. For example:

```
    if (dateString.contains("-")) {
        result = LocalDate.parse(dateString, ddmmmuuFormatter);
    } else {
        result = LocalDate.parse(dateString, ddmmuuuuFormatter);
    }
```

The result is the same as before.

### Use optional parts in the format pattern string

This is the option I like the least, but it’s short and presented for some measure of completeness.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd-MMM-uu][dd/MM/uuuu]", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate result = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
```

The square brackets denote optional parts of the format. So Java first tries to parse using `dd-MMM-uu`. No matter if successful or not it then tries to parse the remainder of the string using `dd/MM/uuuu`. Given your two formats one of the attempts will succeed, and you have parsed the date. The result is still the same as above.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.