# JSP parse String to Date

Tags: jsp, date, jsp-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse any date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java)

I'm trying to parse a Date-String into a Date in my JSP Template. The problem is, that I don't know how the Date-String will look like because it's loaded from different RSS-Feeds which will not always have the same date  format.

For example:

```
<fmt:parseDate value="Tue, 05 Jun 2012 11:45:47" var="date" pattern="EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss" parseLocale="US" />
```

will only work for a date having the format "Tue, 05 Jun 2012 11:45:47"...

I would need something more dynamic as the date could also be "05.06.2012 11:45:47 GMT" or something similar.

I also tried leaving the pattern out but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to get a positive output. But they can't be reliable for every cent.

For example, if the input date is `2012-06-05` and you have patterns `yyyy-MM-dd` and `yyyy-dd-MM` to match with, then resulting month would be `06` i.e. `June` and `05` i.e. `May`. These results would raise a confusion in you and you can't decide whether the output is correct in comparison with RSS server date.

There are similar discussions and suggestions available on SO.

1. [Determine if a String is a valid date before parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962953/determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-before-parsing)
2. [How to convert String to Date without knowing the format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707485/how-to-convert-string-to-date-without-knowing-the-format)
3. [Parse any date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java)
4. and may be more ...